# Component holding value in model after select and clear

Tags: angular, components

I have here a component in which when you type a name, a dropdown list of names appears. You select the name and it goes to a multi list below, then we want the input box to clear. So we run the clear function. It fails. However if we just clear the input normally, it works. So, we are in a bit of a pickle.

Code is below:

**type-ahead.component.html**

```
  <div id="typeAheadContainer" class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
    <label for="" class="d-inline" *ngIf="showTitle">{{title}}</label>
    <button type="button" [disabled]="!hasAccentedCharacters" [ngClass]="{'disable-btn-icon':!hasAccentedCharacters, 'enable-btn-icon':hasAccentedCharacters}"
      class="btn-icon fa fa-globe fa-2x d-inline" (click)="openAccentedCharacterModal()">
    </button>
  </div>
  <span class="row" *ngIf="searching">Searching...</span>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">Sorry, suggestions could not be loaded.</div>
  <div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <form [formGroup]="typeAheadForm" novalidate>
        <ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
          <ngb-highlight [result]="r.typeAheadDisplayName" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight>{{ r.metaData }}
        </ng-template>
        <input
            #typeAheadField
            formControlName="typeAheadField"
            id="typeAheadField"
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            [focusFirst]="false"
            [ngbTypeahead]="nameSearch"
            [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed"
            (selectItem)="selectedItem($event)"
            (focus)="typeAheadFocusSubject.next($event.target.value)"
            placeholder="{{placeHolderText}}"
            [resultTemplate]="rt"
            [inputFormatter]="formatter"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm'>
        <button #clearBtn id="clearBtn" type='reset' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'
                (click)="clearTypeAheadValues($event, clearBtn)" [disabled]="!hasData">Clear
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="row-md-2" *ngIf="showTitle">
        <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm'>
          <button #addBtn id="addSameNameBtn" type='add' class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'
                  (click)="addSameNameValues()" [disabled]="!hasData">Add Same Name
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div >
    <!-- <c2c-type-ahead-name-listing></c2c-type-ahead-name-listing> -->
  </div>

</div>
```

**type-ahead.component.ts (Select function)**

```
private selectedItem(evt: Event): void {
    
    this.hasData = true;

    //return object from typeahead data that matches column value
    let selectedItem: TypeAheadModel = this.typeAheadSearchData.find(x => {
      
      return x.partyId === evt['item'].partyId;
    })

    try {
      //emit service event that will be listened by other components
      this.selectedTypeAheadItem.emit(selectedItem);
      this.typeAheadEventService.typeAheadChangeEvent(selectedItem);


    } catch (err) {
      throw "TypeAhead Selected Item Error" + err;
    } finally {
      this.typeAheadForm.reset();
      this.clearTypeAheadField();
    }

  };
```

**clearTypeAheadValues()**

```
  public clearTypeAheadValues(evt: MouseEvent, clearnBtn: HTMLElement): void {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.clearTypeAheadField();
    this.typeAheadEventService.clearTypeAheadFields();
    this.typeAheadForm.get('typeAheadField').reset();
    this.hasData = false;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `clearTypeAheadValues()`'s implementation wasn't included in the question, I think that the input isn't being cleared because its value is bound to the FormControl named `typeAheadField`.

To reset the value, my instinct is to implement the following inside `clearTypeAheadValues()`: `typeAheadForm.get('typeAheadField').reset(null)`.

Comment: Just tried this, and it failed. Still is hanging out in the field.

Comment: For some reason, `reset()` has been finicky with me in the past. Does the following work? `typeAheadForm.get('typeAheadField').setValue(null)`.

Comment: nope... omg.... how is this, this hard. Would be something with the subscription triggering?

Comment: Okay, the last idea that I have is to reset both the FormControl using the methods above, as well as changing the value of the `ngbTypeahead`'s Observable using `nameSearch.next([])`.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that you haven't told Typeahead not to do its default behavior (replace the model with the selected item.)

So you need to do:

```
selectedItem(evt: Event): void {
   evt.preventDefault();
```